# Getting this error of not enough values to unpack in Francis double shift QR algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, unpack

I am trying to implement the algorithm for Francis double shift QR algorithm but when I try to define this function and input Hessenberg matrix of 3x3 size. It gives error of "Not enough values to unpack"

```
import numpy as np

def francis_double_step_qr(H):
    n = H.shape[0]
    Q = np.identity(n)
    for k in range(n - 2):
        # Find the largest off-diagonal element
        i, j = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(np.abs(H[k+1:, k])), (n - k - 1,))
        i += k + 1
        # Compute the Givens rotation
        c, s = np.cos(H[i, k]), np.sin(H[i, k])
        G = np.identity(n)
        G[k, k], G[i, i] = c, c
        G[k, i], G[i, k] = s, -s
        H = np.dot(G.T, np.dot(H, G))
        Q = np.dot(Q, G)
    return H, Q

A = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]])
H = np.copy(A)
H[1:, 0] = 0
H[2, 1] = 0
H, Q = francis_double_step_qr(H)

print("Hessenberg Matrix after Francis Double Step QR:")
print(H)
print("Orthogonal Matrix Q:")
print(Q)
```

When I run this code by inputting 3x3 or higher sized square matrix it gives error in this line:

```
i, j = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(np.abs(H[k+1:, k])), (n - k - 1,))
```

It works well for 2x2 matrix.
Can anyone please help me figure this out?
Below is the shared image for error traceback.

[image: Error Traceback]

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: I have shared image of the error that I am getting @Klaus D.

Comment: Is this your code, that you have written and debugged yourself, or something you copied (without much understanding)?

Answer (score 1):

Running part of your code, step by step:

```
In [1]: A = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]])                                                                   
...: H = np.copy(A)                                                                                                     
...: H[1:, 0] = 0                                                                                                       
...: H[2, 1] = 0                                                                                                     
In [2]: H                                                                                                               
Out[2]:                                                                                                                 
   array([[ 2,  3,  4],                                                                                                           
          [ 0,  6,  7],                                                                                                           
          [ 0,  0, 10]])
```

For the first `k` iteration:

```
In [3]: n=3; k=0                                                                                                        
In [4]: np.unravel_index(np.argmax(np.abs(H[k+1:, k])), (n - k - 1,))                                                   
Out[4]: (0,)
```

`unravel` has only returned one value, not the 2 that unpacking expects.

I'm not going to take the time to figure out your logic, or show why the (2,2) case works; or whether this works for other `k`.  That's kind of debugging you can do yourself.

The `argmax` returns one value because the selected part of `H` is 1d:

```
In [5]: np.argmax(np.abs(H[k+1:, k]))                                                                                   
Out[5]: 0                                                                                                               
In [6]: H[k+1:,k]                                                                                                       
Out[6]: array([0, 0])
```

Actually it's obvious why (2,2) is different

```
for k in range(n - 2):
```

With `n=2`, the iteration does nothing, so it just returns the unmodifed arrays.  For any larger `n`, it iterates and gets your error.

---

To get two arrays from `unravel` you have to provide a 2 element shape tuple.  You provide just 1 number, so the result is 1 array:

```
In [12]: np.unravel_index(np.arange(9),(10))
Out[12]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64),)
```

With two numbers - 2 arrays:

```
In [13]: np.unravel_index(np.arange(9),(3,4))
Out[13]:
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int64))
```